# Is there a better way to do this find in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, scope

ok so i have this helper

```
def playlist_count(user, site_id)
  user.companies.local(site_id).map(&:playlists).flatten.count
end
```

which will return the playlist count for all the companies

```
class Playlist < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  scope :active, where('end_date >= ? AND player_id IS NOT NULL', Date.today)

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :playlists, :dependent => :destroy
  scope :local, lambda{ |site_id| where(:site_id => site_id) }
```

the problem is it the helper is getting ugly and the other problem is that i need the active playlists (defined by my scope in the playlist model)

Is there a way to clean up my helper or use a scope instead to get the active playlist count for all the users companies

Comment: You should wrap your active scope argument in a lambda so that Date.today is evaluated any time the scope is called. `scope :active, lambda { where(...) }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could run the query the other way round:

```
Playlist.active.where(:company_id => user.companies.local(site_id)).count
```

Comment: Does :company_id => user.companies.local(site_id) produce an SQL in clause because there are more then one record returned

Comment: Yes, it produces something like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM playlist WHERE playlist.company_id IN (SELECT company.id FROM company WHERE …)`

Comment: Ah, this one is obviously better than mine.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply scopes to associations. Try this:

```
user.companies.local(site_id).map { |company| company.playlists.active.count }.sum
```

Another advantage is that it'll execute `select count(*) ...` SQL statement instead of fetching all active playlists from the DB and counting them in Ruby.

If you care about performance it'll be more efficient to join tables and count active playlists for all user's companies in a single SQL statement rather than iterating over companies and making count query for each one of them.